# Paginate merged queries

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have two queries:

```
$posts = Post::all();

$comments = Comment:all();
```

Which I later merge:

```
$merge = $posts->merge($comments);

$all = $merge->sortByDesc(function($result) {
    return $result->created_at;
});
```

How can I paginate the result of the merge? Doing `$all->paginate(25)` does not work.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? You've tagged the question with both laravel-4 and laravel-5

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I'm using v4.2.

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel 5:**

In Laravel 5 it can be easily done by instantiating paginator:

```
$paginator = new Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator($all, $perPage, $currentPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this (`Version-5x`):

```
// Add this at the top of your class
 use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as Paginator;

 // Then use following code:
 $perPage = 10;
 $currentPage = app('request')->get('page') ?: 1; // or $request->get('page') if available
 $paginator = new Paginator($all, $all->count(), $perPage, $currentPage);
```

For `4.2` try this syntax:

```
$items = $all->toArray();
$total = count($items);
$perPage = 10;
$paginator = Paginator::make($items, $total, $perPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 5:**

You can use [spatie/laravel-collection-macros](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-collection-macros).

```
$posts = Post::all();

$comments = Comment:all();

return $comments->merge($posts)->paginate();
```